# Swiftを使って、FTPでJSONファイルをアップロードしたい

Tags: swift, ios, ftp

Swift初心者です。
Swiftを使って、FTPでJSONファイルをアップロードしたいです。
[それらしき記事がGitHubにあった](https://gist.github.com/Nirma/fb9991be776107d17fdcd6ed2aa02876)のでそれを参考にして作っていこうかと思っています。

```
public class FTPUpload {
    fileprivate let ftpBaseUrl: String
    fileprivate let directoryPath: String
    fileprivate let username: String
    fileprivate let password: String

    public init(baseUrl: String, userName: String, password: String, directoryPath: String) {
        self.ftpBaseUrl = baseUrl
        self.username = userName
        self.password = password
        self.directoryPath = directoryPath
    }
}

// MARK: - Steam Setup
extension FTPUpload {
    private func setFtpUserName(for ftpWriteStream: CFWriteStream, userName: CFString) {
        let propertyKey = CFStreamPropertyKey(rawValue: kCFStreamPropertyFTPUserName)
        CFWriteStreamSetProperty(ftpWriteStream, propertyKey, userName)
    }

    private func setFtpPassword(for ftpWriteStream: CFWriteStream, password: CFString) {
        let propertyKey = CFStreamPropertyKey(rawValue: kCFStreamPropertyFTPPassword)
        CFWriteStreamSetProperty(ftpWriteStream, propertyKey, password)
    }

    fileprivate func ftpWriteStream(forFileName fileName: String) -> CFWriteStream? {
        let fullyQualifiedPath = "ftp://\(ftpBaseUrl)/\(directoryPath)/\(fileName)"

        guard let ftpUrl = CFURLCreateWithString(kCFAllocatorDefault, fullyQualifiedPath as CFString, nil) else { return nil }
        let ftpStream = CFWriteStreamCreateWithFTPURL(kCFAllocatorDefault, ftpUrl)
        let ftpWriteStream = ftpStream.takeRetainedValue()
        setFtpUserName(for: ftpWriteStream, userName: username as CFString)
        setFtpPassword(for: ftpWriteStream, password: password as CFString)
        return ftpWriteStream
    }
}


// MARK: - FTP Write
extension FTPUpload {
    public func send(data: Data, with fileName: String, success: @escaping ((Bool)->Void)) {

        guard let ftpWriteStream = ftpWriteStream(forFileName: fileName) else {
            success(false)
            return
        }

        if CFWriteStreamOpen(ftpWriteStream) == false {
            print("Could not open stream")
            success(false)
            return
        }

        let fileSize = data.count
        let buffer = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>.allocate(capacity: fileSize)
        data.copyBytes(to: buffer, count: fileSize)

        defer {
            CFWriteStreamClose(ftpWriteStream)
            buffer.deallocate(capacity: fileSize)
        }

        var offset: Int = 0
          var dataToSendSize: Int = fileSize

          var shouldContinue = true
          repeat {
              if (CFWriteStreamCanAcceptBytes(ftpWriteStream)) {
                  let bytesWritten = CFWriteStreamWrite(ftpWriteStream, &buffer[offset], dataToSendSize)
                  print("ftp bytes written: \(bytesWritten)")
                  if bytesWritten > 0 {
                      offset += bytesWritten.littleEndian
                      dataToSendSize -= bytesWritten
                      continue
                  } else if bytesWritten < 0 {
                      // ERROR
                      print("FTPUpload - ERROR")
                      shouldContinue = false
                      break
                  } else if bytesWritten == 0 {
                      // SUCCESS
                      print("FTPUpload - Completed!!")
                      shouldContinue = false
                      break
                  }
              } else {
                  usleep(200000)
                  print(".", separator: "", terminator: "")
              }
          } while shouldContinue

          success(true)
    }
}
```

実行する関数は、[スタックオーバーフロー(英語版)のもの](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46107445/ftp-image-upload-causes-image-to-be-cut-off-swift)を参考に、以下のようにしたいのですが
元の記事が画像をアップロードするようになっており、引数にファイルを指定する項目があります。
JSONをファイルとして保存する方法が分かりません。

```
func ftpuploder()
{

    let ftpup = FTPUpload(baseUrl: "mysite.com", userName: "user@mysite.com", password: "password", directoryPath: "")

    let testJSON = {"test1":1,"test2":2}
    var JSONdata = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: testJSON, options: JSONSerialization.WritingOptions.init())

    let JSON_NSData = JSONdata as Data

    ftpup.send(data: JSON_NSData, with: "cloudpowa.jpg", success: {(success) -> Void in
        if !success {
            print("Failed upload!")
        }
        else {
            print("image uploaded!")
        }
    })
}
```

JSONをファイルとして保存したほうが良いのか
それともファイルとして保存しなくてもFTPアップロードできるのか
良い方法があったら教えてください。

※このコードでは短いJSONの内容になっていますが、実際には数MB程度の大きなテキストをアップロードするつもりなのでFTPを使いたいと思っています。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FTPUpload の send はアップロードしたい内容を Data型 で引数に受け取ります。
また、 `JSONSerialization.data(...)` は受け取ったオブジェクトをJSONにして、 Data型 で返します。

なのでファイルに書き出す必要はありません。
JSONSerializationでData型にしたものをそのまま `ftpup.send(data: ... )` に渡せば良いです。

（参考にしたStackoverflowの内容は画像ファイルを読んでJPEGのData型に変換してから送っています）

Comment: ありがとうございます。ということは、withオプションを覗いて`ftpup.send(data: JSON_NSData, success: {`という形で書いてあげれば良さそうでしょうか？

Comment: そのはずです。試してみてください。ちなみに as の行は不要で、JSONdata の方でも問題ないと思います

Comment: あ、ごめんなさい。よくコメント読めていませんでした。`with:` は省略できません。 `with: fileName` で渡すのは送り先に保存するときのファイル名ではないでしょうか？

Answer (score 2):

ただファイルをFTPでアップロードするだけであればJSONにする必要は無いと思います。
ファイルを用意し、FTPでアップロードの手順だと思います。
また、すでにあるファイルがJSONファイルであれば、同様にそのままアップロード
すればいいと思います。
JSONをファイルとして保存する方法が分かりません。とありますが、
何らかのファイルをJSONフォーマットに変換するという意味でしょうか？
それであればFTPとは関係なく、特定のフォーマットのファイルを読み込み、
それをJSONフォーマットに変換して保存することになります。
その後、そのファイルをFTPでアップロードすることになります。

FTPのアクセスはこのようなライブラリもあるようです。
http://lloydsargent.github.io/BlackRaccoon/

Comment: ありがとうございます。すでにあるファイルをアップロードするイメージではなく、プログラム内でJSONを自動生成し、そのJSONをファイルとして保存などしてFTPアップロードするようなイメージで考えています。